# Building(With ant) a jar with it's main in the default package

Tags: java, ant, build, jar

I was wondering if anyone knew how to set the Main-class property in an Ant Build xml to look in the default package? I've tried just "Main", but it doesn't seem to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Main-Class` attribute of `manifest`:

```
<jar jarfile="${jar.name}">
  <fileset dir="${classes.dir}">
     <include name="**/*.*"/>
  </fileset>
  <manifest>
     <attribute name="Main-Class" value="MyApp"/>
  </manifest>
</jar>
```

[Docs for Ant Jar Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html)

Comment: I believe he's asking about a class that doesn't specify a package, just `MyApp`

Comment: @Unreal - have you opened the jarfile with a tool like 7zip and verified it has everything it should?